# Swift ios error in navigating back

Tags: ios, swift, navigation

I have use the following code below . to navigate but i have tried all possible idea i have to navigate back but i always received an error. like Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window . when using the code below what is the best way to navigate back ? or to go to another view?

```
if let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ScoreViewController") as? ScoreViewController
{
    present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: if you want to navigate your previous VC, then just use `dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are presenting the view controller not **pushing** it. To come back to the controller, write down the below controller:-

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using *NavigationController* to push one *ViewController* to other then for navigate back you have to use **Pop** like this,

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

and if you are using Modal Controller to present another Controller then for navigate back you have to use **dismiss** like this,

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Let me know in case of any queries.

Comment: @Sir , can i trigger view did load after i use this dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)?

Comment: No, viewWillAppear called at that time

Comment: cause i wanna trigger viewdidload after i diss

Comment: You can do that things in viewWillAppear too

Comment: You can eventually create delegate to call methods after dismiss

Comment: ive tried  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
                super.viewWillAppear(animated)
                viewDidLoad()
            } but it keep repeating the view , it keep repeating dismiss

Comment: when i click close the page appear again